# Intergrate DJI UXSDK to My Android Studio3.5 failed

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I am tring to intergrate DJI UXSDK to my Android project on Android Studio3.5,and I am following its [official doc](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/android-tutorials/UXSDKDemo.html) ,fortunately, "Sync with Gradle File" successed,however,when I tried to build and install my project,it failed,And I tried to using Gradle File in [DJIUXSDKDemo](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-UXSDKDemo),failed again,I still can't build my project,does anyone can help me? thanks a lot.

Comment: By the way, I am just intergrating UXSDK now, and I don't add any java statement about UXSDK until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this question by changing my gradle file, the guide in official doc is following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
    }

    ...

    packagingOptions{
        doNotStrip "*/*/libdjivideo.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libSDKRelativeJNI.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFlyForbid.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libduml_vision_bokeh.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libyuv2.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libGroudStation.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFRCorkscrew.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libUpgradeVerify.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFR.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libDJIFlySafeCore.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libdjifs_jni.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libsfjni.so"
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }
}

dependencies {
   ...
    compile ('com.dji:dji-sdk:4.11.2')
    provided ('com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.11.2')
}
```

Unfortunately, it is not complete,so we should change to this:

```
packagingOptions{
        doNotStrip "*/*/libdjivideo.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libSDKRelativeJNI.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFlyForbid.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libduml_vision_bokeh.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libyuv2.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libGroudStation.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFRCorkscrew.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libUpgradeVerify.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFR.so"

        pickFirst 'lib/*/libstlport_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/*/libRoadLineRebuildAPI.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/*/libGNaviUtils.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/*/libGNaviMapex.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/*/libGNaviData.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/*/libGNaviMap.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/*/libGNaviSearch.so'
        pickFirst 'assets/location_map_gps_locked.png'
        pickFirst 'assets/location_map_gps_3d.png'

        exclude '/lib/armeabi-v7a/libChineseFontPkg.so'
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
```

and add following into your dependencies:

```
 implementation 'com.dji:dji-uxsdk:4.12'
    compileOnly 'com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.12'
```